# Node.js Application Startup Error with GridDB

Tags: griddb

I'm working on an IoT project and opted to utilize GridDB as the database for storing sensor
time-series data. After successfully installing essential packages such as GridDB C client and
griddb_node package, I attempted to launch the application, it encounters an error and fails.

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189
return process.dlopen(module, path.toNamespacedPath(filename));
^
Error: \\?\D:\GridDB\node_modules\griddb_node\lib\griddb_client.node is not a
valid Win32 application.
\\?\D:\work\upwork\GridDB\node_modules\griddb_node\lib\griddb_client.node
←[90m at Object.Module._extensions..node
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1189:18)←[39m
←[90m at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m
←[90m at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)←[39m
←[90m at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)←[39m
at Object.<anonymous>
(D:\GridDB\node_modules\←[4mgriddb_node←[24m\lib\griddb_node.js:1:14)
←[90m at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)←[39m
←[90m at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)←[39m
←[90m at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)←[39m
←[90m at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)←[39m {
code: ←[32m'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'←[39m
}
```

Enironment

Operating System : Windows 10
Node Version : 16.15.0

```
    const griddb = require("griddb_node");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const factory = griddb.StoreFactory.getInstance();
    const store = factory.getStore({
        host: "239.0.0.1",
        port: 31999,
        clusterName: "defaultCluster",
        username: "admin",
        password: "admin",
    });
```

I employed nvm to switch my Node.js version from 16.15.0 to 10.16.3. but the problem still persists.